# Infinitive usage

Tags: to-infinitive

I cannot understand the usage of infinitive in this sentence.

> Japan went to save stranded resident and fight flood caused by one of
>   worst typhoon to hit country in recent history.

Please explain why 'to hit' has been used here . Providing any reference material will be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Did you write it?

Comment: is it a newspaper (online or print) headline?

Comment: @smock it is written in a context of newspaper.not a headline

Comment: Can you edit the question to describe what your problem is with the sentence, and where you got it from. To me it sounds like a rather typical machine translation - a bit garbled.

Comment: @simon at rcl.i edited it.please see that why ' to hit' is used.is it a reduced form of any clause?

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is that infinitives may follow superlatives, ordinal numbers, and a few other words that have similar functions. This explains why, in your sentence, the infinitive **to hit** follows the phrase ***worst* typhoon**

Michael Swan (*Practical English Usage*, 2017 edition, section 101) writes the following:

> **superlatives, etc: *the oldest athlete to win . . .***
>
> Superlatives can be followed by an infinitive structure. The meaning is similar to an identifying relative clause.
>
> *He's the **oldest athlete ever to win** an Olympic gold medal.* (= . . . who has
> ever won . . .)
>
> This structure is also common with *first, second, third,* etc, *next, last* and *only.*
>
> *Who was the **first person to climb** Everest without oxygen?*
> *The **next to arrive** was Mrs Patterson.*
> *She's the **only scientist to have won** three Nobel prizes.*

Most of Swan's examples illustrate the words being used as adjectives or determiners. The same rule applies when they are used as nouns:

> The **first to escape** the burning building was Jason Bourne.
> The **youngest to win** the competition was Jack Reacher.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "A" is *hit* by "B", we mean "B" affects "A".

From Cambridge, one meaning of "hit" that is relevant to your context is

> to have an unpleasant or negative effect on a person or thing

Look at these examples:

> *"Production has been badly **hit** by the strike."* - This means that the strike created negative impacts on production. Due to the strike, factories were closed as workers were on the streets. This stopped production and there were losses.
>
> *"Demand for transatlantic flights has been **hit** by fears of terrorist attacks."* - This means that because people were afraid of terrorist attacks, they did not want to travel by plane. The demand for tickets fell, and airline companies incurred severe losses. The demand for tickets was severely *"hit"* or *"impacted"* by fears of terrorist attacks.

In your case,

> ... one of [the] worst typhoons to hit [the] country in recent history.

means that there were several typhoons that happened before, but this one was the worst one. Because there was flood and severe damage to the country, the appropriate word is "hit". The country was *badly affected* by the typhoon. The *impact* of the typhoon was too severe.